# Xpath selecting <a href=""> value

Tags: php, xpath

I am trying to select value from a link but, don't know how to solve this problem.

```
<li id ="listing" class="listing premium first">
   <header>
      <h2>
        <a href="#">value</a>
      </h2>
   </header>
</li>
```

I tried with this code and didn't work.

```
echo $test = $xpath->evaluate('//li[contains(@class,"listing")]//header//h2//a')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Here's all of my code:

```
<?php 
    $getURL = file_get_contents('realestate.com.kh/…'); 
    $dom = new DOMDocument(); 
    @$dom->loadHTML($getURL); 
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 
    /* echo $xpath->evaluate("normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(//p[contains(‌​text(),'Property ID:')][1], 'Property ID:'), '–'))");*/ 
    echo $test = $xpath->evaluate('//li[contains(@class,"listing")]//header//h2//a')->item(0)->no‌​deValue;
?>
```

And here's the actual error I get:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in W:\Xampp\htdocs\X\index.php on line 9

Is something wrong with this code? I don't know how to make this work. pls help me anyone. I thanks u all.

Comment: What is not working, exactly? What error do you get? Your question is vague. I ran this in a quick PhpFiddle and your code works just fine. Your code example does not provide how you are creating the `$xpath` variable and/or loading in the HTML. Chances are that is where your problem lies.

Comment: I got this erorr Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in W:\Xampp\htdocs\X\index.php on line 9

Comment: all of my code <?php
$getURL = file_get_contents('http://realestate.com.kh/residential-for-sale-in-phnom-penh-chroy-changvar-chroy-changvar-2-beds-condo-1001192321/');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($getURL);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

/*echo $xpath->evaluate("normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(//p[contains(text(),'Property ID:')][1], 'Property ID:'), '–'))");*/

echo $test = $xpath->evaluate('//li[contains(@class,"listing")]//header//h2//a')->item(0)->nodeValue;

Comment: Please read this reference to understand the error you're getting:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/26572398#26572398

What I believe is happening is that the HTML you think you're getting from the site, is not actually the HTML you are getting.

The answer that I linked to has an example using xpath which is relevant to what you're doing. It will help you understand the problem.

Comment: Also here is the link to the entire reference on StackOverflow about PHP errors in general -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/

Comment: have you tried `//li[contains(@class,"listing")]//a/@href`  ?